# How to unwrapped dictionary optional value?

Tags: dictionary, swift3

`typealias` of dictionary  key with optional value

```
typealias JSON = [String:Any?]
```

And here is my dictionary

```
    var createAfterStr: String? = nil
    var createBeforeStr: String? = nil

    if let createdAfter = statesByScope.createdAfter, let afterStr = toString(date: createdAfter) {
        createAfterStr = afterStr
    }
    if let createdBefore = statesByScope.createdBefore, let beforeStr = toString(date: createdBefore) {
        createBeforeStr = beforeStr
    }

 let params:  JSON  = [
            "scope_id": statesByScope.scopeId,
            "createdAfter" : createAfterStr ?? nil,
            "createdBefore" : createBeforeStr ?? nil,
            "limit" : "4"]
```

and when i send it with as a parameter curl request . i seem url make :

```
 var request = URLRequest(baseUrl: baseUrl, path: path, method: method, params: params)
     request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
 var urlrequst : URLRequest?
        do{
            urlrequst =  try  Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default.encode(request, with: params)    
        }catch let error {
           completion(nil, ServiceError.custom(String(describing: error)))
        }
          print(urlrequst)
```

> https://www.demo.life/post?limit=Optional(%224%22)&createdBefore=nil&scope_id=Optional(%22a409f4c8-d62b-4e03-ae62-4aa17d8c74fa%22)&createdAfter=nil

it is really wired part with `Optional`.

so how  to unwrapped 
dictionally optional value? or  do i miss anything?  thanks

Comment: You should read the language guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: `createAfterStr ?? nil` "If `createAfterStr` is `nil`, then use a default value of `nil` instead"... doesn't make sense

Comment: @Alexander thanks . update my question hope it will clear now . if  you like it please up vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that. A JSON dictionary has never optional values.

Create `params` with the distinct non-optional values and then add the key / value pairs which can be `nil`.
If `createAfterStr` or `createBeforeStr` are `nil` the key will be skipped.

```
typealias JSON = [String:Any]

var params: JSON = ["scope_id": statesByScope.scopeId, "limit" : "4"]
params["createdAfter"] = createAfterStr
params["createdBefore"] = createBeforeStr
```